# 未ログイン時に回答欄の下に表示されるメッセージを改善したい

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

未ログインの状態で回答を行おうとすると簡単な説明が表示されますが、「てにをは」の使い方に違和感があったり説明もやや不親切な気がするので、この文言を修正したいと思っています。

しかし https://ja.traducir.win や transifex では該当する文字列が見つかりません。

**修正案**

- スタック・オーバーフロー**に**参加してくれて ...
- 次の項目**は**避けてください ...
- (**既に投稿した質問に対する**)更なる説明 ...

併せて、可能であれば「回答に満たないコメント投稿(≒質問に対する質問)」に対する説明書きも
あるとより親切になるのかなと思います。

---

**現在の表示**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

If you try to post an answer without being logged in, a brief explanation is displayed.  But some particles are grammatically incorrect and the description is somewhat unfriendly.  The strings could not be found on either Traducir nor transifex.

I think we need to improve these sentences as follows.

- スタック・オーバーフロー**に**参加してくれて ...
- 次の項目**は**避けてください ...
- (**既に投稿した質問に対する**)更なる説明 ...